# How can I adjust these cards so they are responsive using Boostrap 4?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How can I have each `row`display 4 cards and, of course, if the screen size changes, make them stack. Ideally, there should be some space in between them. I've tried all possible combinations I could research.

```css
#cardsContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1200px;
  }

  .card {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    width: calc(25% - 16px);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    outline-width: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }

  /* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
  .row {
    margin: 0 -5px;
  }

  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .card {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<div id="cardsContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-group">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="2">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><label for="status">Status:</label>
              <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                <option value="Published">Published</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group img">
              <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
              <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="post">Post:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
              <a href="https://posts.gdle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.glde/nTUL97"></a></div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden="">
              <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="2">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><label for="status">Status:</label>
              <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                <option value="Published">Published</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group img">
              <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
              <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="post">Post:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
              <a href="https://posts.glde/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.glde/nTUL97"></a></div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden="">
              <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="2">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><label for="status">Status:</label>
              <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                <option value="Published">Published</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group img">
              <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
              <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="post">Post:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
              <a href="https://posts.dgle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posdts.gle/nTUL97"></a></div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden="">
              <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="2">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><label for="status">Status:</label>
              <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                <option value="Published">Published</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group img">
              <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
              <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="post">Post:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
              <a href="https://posts.gdle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.gle/ndTUL97"></a></div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden="">
              <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="2">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                <select class="form-control" value="1">
                  <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select><label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"><label for="status">Status:</label>
              <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                <option value="Published">Published</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group img">
              <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
              <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="post">Post:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
              <a href="https://posdts.gle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.dgle/nTUL97"></a></div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden="">
              <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [bootstrap docs on responsive classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns), I used them in this code (col-md-6) so that from tablets onwards the display was two cards, while on larger screens it shows 4 cards (col-xl-3)

Ps. I cleaned up the code and added the meta viewport, it is important for mobile viewing!

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

```css
#cardsContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*height: 1000px; WHY?*/
  }

  .card {;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    flex-direction: inherit!important;
  }

  /* .row {
    margin: 0 -5px;
  }
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  } */

  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .card {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>-->
<body>

<div id="cardsContainer">
    <div class="row crd-group">
        
        <!--CARD DEMO-->
        <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-3 m-1 m-md-2 card">
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="2">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Status:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                        <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                        <option value="Published">Published</option>
                        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
                    <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="post">Post:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
                    <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
                    <a href="https://posts.gdle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.glde/nTUL97"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--CARD DEMO-->
        <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-3 m-1 m-md-2 card">
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="2">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Status:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                        <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                        <option value="Published">Published</option>
                        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
                    <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="post">Post:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
                    <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
                    <a href="https://posts.gdle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.glde/nTUL97"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--CARD DEMO-->
        <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-3 m-1 m-md-2 card">
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="2">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Status:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                        <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                        <option value="Published">Published</option>
                        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
                    <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="post">Post:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
                    <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
                    <a href="https://posts.gdle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.glde/nTUL97"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--CARD DEMO-->
        <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-3 m-1 m-md-2 card">
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="2">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="1">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 mt-3">
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" value="2023-01-29">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Status:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" value="Planned">
                        <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
                        <option value="Published">Published</option>
                        <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="status">Image URL:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" value="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg">
                    <a href="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" target="_blank">
                        <img src="https://stimg.cardekho.com/images/carexteriorimages/930x620/Tesla/Model-S/5252/1611840999494/front-left-side-47.jpg" class="card-img" height="190px">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                    <label for="post">Post:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control post">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3">
                    <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
                    <a href="https://posts.gdle/nTUL97" target="_blank">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="https://posts.glde/nTUL97"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" hidden="">
                    <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Impressive! Thanks! I've been in programming not for a long time and didn't have to do with front-end...oh boy, this is another world!